# Looking for a Regular Expression (limited string)

Tags: regex

I need to validate an alphanumeric string. For this, I use this regular expression: `^(?!\s*$).+`

but I need to have between 1 and 20 characters. I test with `^(?!\s*$).{1,20}+` but it is not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Loose the `+`. The `{a,b}` and the `+` are both quantifiers you only need the `{}`. Also you need the `$` at the end as well.

Comment: @fejese your change works for me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a lookahead here. Simply you could try the below regex to validate an alphanumeric string.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}$
```

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` Matches an alphanumeric character.
- `{1,20}` would repeats the previous token `[A-Za-z0-9]` from 1 to 20 times.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: This is another solution. Thanks!